# F#'s DescriptiveStatistics unknown?

Tags: f#

I am currently converting a project in F# to Python, I am a relative amateur in F#, please...what on earth does this line do...

```
       let stats = new DescriptiveStatistics(list)
```

I cant find a good definition of DescriptiveStatistics anywhere! Please help!
Many thanks

Comment: `DescriptiveStatistics` is a class that is declared somewhere in the libraries that you are using. It's not a built-in F# thing, it's a piece of code that somebody created and you're using. If you use an IDE with F# support (e.g. VSCode), you can hover on that identifier to see where it's coming from.

Answer (score 2):

That is very likely from [MathNet](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/descriptivestatistics.html).

Check the beginning of your F# for the line:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.Statistics;
```

Comment: Indeed, I find MathNet.Numerics.Statistics, but I can't find any proper example or explanation of this on the internet?!?! Does anyone know of any good examples? Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/DescriptiveStatistics.html
"...in case you need to gather a whole set of statistical characteristics in one pass, is provided by the DescriptiveStatistics class:..." Thanks for your help guys